# Javascripts code stops working

Tags: javascript

the problem it's about a roulette that spins every 1 min,
Problem : When I switch from one tab to another on google chrome or any other navigators, the script stops running and the roulette stops (and I need to go back to the tab again in order to make the script work)

image roulette = animation of game

```
 //<![CDATA[
        var myRoll = {
            nbr : [14, 1, 13, 2, 12, 3, 11, 0, 4, 10, 5, 9, 6, 8 ,7],

            initRoll : function(){
                var Ccolor;
                var nbrCtn = $(".nbr-ctn");
                for(j = 0; j < 6 ; j++){
                    for(i = 0; i < this.nbr.length; i++){
                        Ccolor = "";
                        if(this.nbr[i] === 0 ){
                            Ccolor = "nbr-green";
                        }else if(this.nbr[i] > 7){
                            Ccolor = "nbr-black";
                        }else{
                            Ccolor = "nbr-red";
                        }

                        var elem = '<div class="nbr '+ Ccolor +'" >'+ this.nbr[i] +'</div>';
                        nbrCtn.append(elem);
                    }
                }           
            },

            lastResult : function(n){
                Ccolor = "";
                if(n === 0 ){
                    Ccolor = "nbr nbr-green";
                }else if(n > 7){
                    Ccolor = "nbr nbr-black";
                }else{
                    Ccolor = "nbr nbr-red";
                }

                var nbrResult = $(".lastResult > div").length;
                if(nbrResult === 5 ){
                    $(".lastResult div:first-child").remove();
                }

                var elem = '<div class="circle '+ Ccolor +'" >'+ n +'</div>';
                $(".lastResult").append(elem);
            },

            rollAnimation : function(offset, n){
                var prog = $(".progress-line");
                if(offset){
                    prog.width("100%");
                    var nbrCtn = $(".nbr-ctn");
                    nbrCtn.css("left" , "0px");                 
                    nbrCtn.animate({left: "-"+ offset +".5px"}, 6000, 'easeInOutQuint', function(){
                        myRoll.lastResult(n);
                        myRoll.countDown();
                    });
                }
            },

            getRandomInt : function(min, max){
                min = Math.ceil(min);
                max = Math.floor(max);
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
            },

            startRoll : function(n){
                var nbrCtn = $(".nbr-ctn");
                var gAnim = $("#game-animation");
                var idx = this.nbr.indexOf(n) + this.nbr.length * 4;
                var elmWidth = nbrCtn.find(".nbr").width();
                var offset = idx * elmWidth - (gAnim.width() / 2);
                offset = this.getRandomInt(offset + 5, offset + elmWidth - 5);
                this.rollAnimation(offset, n);
            },

            countDown : function(){

                var prog = $(".progress-line");
                var gameStatus = $(".rolling > span");
                prog.animate({width : "0px"}, {
                    duration: 30000,
                    step: function(now){
                        var rt = (now*3) / 100;
                        gameStatus.html("Closing in " + rt.toFixed(2));
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                        // when the progress bar be end 
                        gameStatus.html("Rolling ...");
                        myRoll.startRoll(myRoll.getRandomInt(0, 14));
                    },
                    easing: "linear"
                });
            }
        };


        window.onload = function(){
            myRoll.initRoll();
            myRoll.countDown();
        };
//]]>
```

[image]

Comment: If you change the tab on your browser, in that time period the tab will be paused, so not be able to execute javascript. This is not an error, and this is not solvable.

Comment: you want javascript to keep running when window is dismissed?

Comment: exactly Kevin Kloet

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to implement things in following way (this is just way out).
Basic concept behind bellow code is calculate lag between tab switch and set current state accordingly.

```
var prevTime,curTime;
var rate = 500; //(miliseconds) you can set it.

function update()
{
    var diffTime = curTime - prevTime;
    if (diffTime >= rate)
    {

        //check if difference is more than step value then calculate
        //current state accordingly. so you will always be updated as you calculating lags.


        // e.g. diffTime = 1500;
        // you will need to jump Math.floor(diffTime/rate) which is 3.
        // calculate current state.

        //your code....
        prevTime = curTime;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```